# Saving files from virtual machine to file server

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04 as a virtual machine on Limetech Unraid Server. Unraid functions as the file server and can use NFS and/or SMB. I want to be able to point any program on the vm to the file server so it will store most of it's information on the file server instead of the virtual drive. The way in which the file server directory is presented to the program does not matter, though presenting it as a mounted directory is preferable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious what is your use case for this? Why not just clone the repository to your physical machine from your GitLab? You can configure GitLab to mirror a remote: http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html and you can also use the same technique configure it to push to a remote, rather than pull, if you have EE. You could also script your remote to pull from GitLab every hour, which is how we solved a similar problem where I work.

Comment: That is not a bad idea. It is a good workaround for my problem with gitlab, however, I would still like to know how to access a file server from ubuntu for other applications besides gitlab.

Comment: There are a lot of ways and most (all?) of them are entirely dependent on what virtualization you are using (VMWare, VirtualBox, Hyper-V, ??), what the host machine OS is, what protocol the share is using (SMB, CIFS, NFS, ?), and how you want to expose it to the VM (as a network file server, as a mounted directory, ??). Update your question with those specifics and you will be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Based on your edit, if you create a network share on the file server and expose your network to the VM it should be able to mount the share. But are you saying that the file server itself is also the host machine for the VM? If that's the case using a network share may be unnecessary and you could probably just share the storage directly.  I'm not very familiar with limeraid.

Comment: The point I am getting at is that I do not know how to mount a share. I have not used Linux very much, and so do not know much about its commands. I am not certain whether your second suggestion will work with unraid, I will have to look into it, but for now I just want to know how to mount a network share, if not for this particular case, then just for the sake of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Install cifs-utils

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Create a (empty) directory to mount the share to, e.g.

```
# name and location are up to you
sudo mkdir /media/netshare
```

Edit your /etc/fstab file like so (only if you are the only user of the Linux VM - fstab is readable by other users)

```
//servername/sharename  /media/netshare  cifs username=myusername,password=mypassword,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

then run

```
sudo mount -a
```

For more details and other scenarios, such as no password or using a credential file, [see here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)